# Compare columns across multiple data frames in R

Tags: r

I am analyzing data stored in separate monthly files across 5 years. The individual datasets are expected to have different numbers and mixes of rows (cases) per dataset, but should have the same variables and variable names. However, I know from looking at them that some do not, and that I will have to manipulate these before merging all datasets into one data frame. Is there any way of automating the process of identifying these, in particular to document the changes I make?

For example, say I have the following 4 datasets:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3), age = c(10, 20, 30), color = 
       c("green", "purple", "gold"))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), age = c(10, 20, 30, 40), color = 
       c("green", "purple", "gold", "blue"))
df3 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 3, 4), age = c(10, 30, 40), colour = 
       c("green", "gold", "blue"), kids = c(0, 1, 1))
df4 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 4), color = c("green", "purple", 
       "blue"), age = c(10, 20, 40))
```

All 4 datasets should look like df1 and df2, but df3 has a different spelling for one variable ("colour") and extra variable ("kids"), while df4 reverses the order of two variables ("age" and "color").

I can visually inspect column numbers and names to identify problems, like so:

```
df.list <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
df.cols <- lapply(df.list, function(x) ncol(x))
df.names <- lapply(df.list, function(x) names(x))
```

Output

```
> df.cols
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 3

> df.names
[[1]]
[1] "id"    "age"   "color"

[[2]]
[1] "id"    "age"   "color"

[[3]]
[1] "id"     "age"    "colour" "kids"  

[[4]]
[1] "id"    "color" "age"
```

But I have many more variables and and datasets. Is there a more efficient way to do this, to automatically and reproducibly identify mismatches? I have only found ways to compare across pairs of datasets. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: It is better to have a `list` of datasets instead of creating multiple objects in the global env.  If you want to get all the objects in a list.  `mget(paste0("df", 1:4))` For matching, perhaps `stringdist` could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way can be

```
dflist <- mget(paste0("df", 1:4))

nametest <- sapply(dflist,function(x){names(x) %in% names(df1)})
$df1
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

$df2
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE

$df3
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

$df4
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

And then to see only the problematic ones

```
quickview <- unlist(sapply(nametest,function(x){if(!all(x))"name pb"}))
      df3 
"name pb"
```

This way you verify names and column at the same time (additional column with other name will give a FALSE in nametest).
If you want the index of the wrong columns:

```
index <- sapply(dflist,function(x){
  which(!names(x) %in% names(df1))})

$df1
integer(0)

$df2
integer(0)

$df3
[1] 3 4

$df4
integer(0)
```

And if you want the names of the columns:

```
wrongnames <- sapply(dflist,function(x){
  indx <- which(!names(x) %in% names(df1))
  names(x)[indx]
  })
```

Comment: Thank you @denis, worked perfectly! For documentation purposes, I'm trying to take it a step further and index all of the FALSE elements across all returned lists in `nametest`.

Comment: Sorry that was incomplete. How can I produce a subset of `nametest` that is an index of all the FALSE elements? All of the datasets have problems, so I'd like a single list of all mismatches for documentation purposes. I've been searching and trying things to no avail, here is my latest attempt that doesn't work. `probs <- unlist(sapply(nametest, function(x) class(x)==FALSE))`

Comment: i posted the answer. If it suits you, you can accept the answer. If you have further question, the best is to ask a new question